# Create Library of multiple XSD

Tags: xsd

I have a potential of having quite a lot of small XSD's containing individual types of a big project. (Components)

I also have a biggish number of XSD's requiring a large number of these individual XSD's. (Screens)

I know I could import each one of the "Components" into each "Screen" XSD. But its a lot of work to do on each one.

What I was hoping I could do is import each one of these "Components" into a single XSD (ComponentLibrary) and then just import this one "ComponentLibrary" into each "Screen" XSD.

I wrote the code that I thought may have been what was needed but it doesn't seem to want to work. I get errors that it is undeclared.

**TF.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://namespace.com/TF"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="TFType">
        <xs:attribute name="size" type="xs:decimal" />
        <xs:attribute name="colour" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**ComponentsLibrary.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://namespace.com/ComponentsLibrary"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tf="http://namespace.com/TF"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="TF.xsd" namespace="http://namespace.com/TF"/>
    <xs:element name="TF" type="tf:TFType" />
</xs:schema>
```

**Screen1.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:cl="http://namespace.com/ComponentsLibrary" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="ComponentsLibrary.xsd" namespace="http://namespace.com/ComponentsLibrary" />

    <xs:element name="tfTitle" type="cl:TF" />
</xs:schema>
```

**Error I get**

```
Screen1.xsd (8:3) Error Type 'http://namespace.com/Components:TF' is not declared.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your components library schema declares an *element* TF, not a *type* TF, hence the error in the Screen1.xsd.

If you really want to make the TF type available in ComponentLibrary then you could use a [chameleon schema approach](http://www.xfront.com/ZeroOneOrManyNamespaces.html#mixed).

- TF.xsd should have no namespace
- ComponentLibrary should then **include** (not import) TF.xsd
- All types in TF.xsd are now available under the ComponentLibrary namespace

Comment: Works Beautifully. Thank you.